# How do I exclude functions from properties on formal verification model?

Tags: pact-lang

I want to exclude the genesis mint function from the conserves-mass property

```
(module account GOVERNANCE 
@doc "Account doc"  
@model
[ (defproperty conserves-mass
    (= (column-delta ledger 'balance ) 0.0))]
...
(defun transfer-create:string
    ( sender:string
      receiver:string
      receiver-guard:guard
      amount:decimal )
@doc "create account when transfer doc"
@model [ (property conserves-mass)] <- I want to exclude mint function here 

...
```

I found this example
https://github.com/kadena-io/pact/blob/4971ab6078b75eb612d83d56f1e7cd139a5a2ba8/examples/verified-accounts/accounts.pact#L27

where they do an except logic but it makes no sense to me how this 'except work and I can't make it work. I don't know what I'm missing.

I found nothing about this on the documentation
https://pact-language.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pact-properties.html

```
  @model
    [
...
     ; every function should conserve mass except for the admin fund-account,
     ; and debit / credit which should be private
     (property conserves-mass
       {'except: [fund-account, debit, credit]})
...
    ]
```

Comment: what do you mean with "not working for me". Did you get an error or what is the output and how is it different from the expected output?